# Unity3D: Adding charged force in relation to position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform

I am trying to make a game which "kind of" simulates the shooting of the "worms" game. The player can choose the position (circular) of an object  and then, the force that is applied to the object should move in the direction its pointing towards. I tried using the `AddForce(transform.right)` code, but it would just go to the right. (2D BoxCollider and RigidBody2D)

Then comes the hard part, making the player choose the force by charging the power. When the player holds down the "f" key, I want the power to go up to a certain point. Once it reaches that point, I want it to go down again and then up again, so the player can choose the power he wants. I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: I've never done this in Unity, but I imagine the `transformation.right` is a vector. So you'd have to specify the chosen vector by the player. The 'charging' would just be a variable that would start looping round when a button is pressed, where the loop checks for the key being released, thus exiting the loop with a certain value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've did Unity coding, so there may be some minor errors with my syntax but it should give you an idea of how to accomplish this. Your best bet for the loop is to use a coroutine to not block the main thread.

in Update() check for 'on key down' for F and start this coroutine:

```
IEnumerator Cycle()  
{
 float max = 10.0f;
 float min = 1.0f;
 float interval = 0.5f;

  do 
   {             
     for(int i=min;i<max;i++)
     {
       PowerValue = i;
       yield return new waitforseconds(interval);
      if(!input.getkey(f))
          break;
     }
     for(int i=max;i>min;i--)
     {
       PowerValue = i;
       yield return new waitforseconds(interval);
       if(!input.getkey(f))
          break;
     }

   } while(input.getkey(f));
}
```

And back in update() use that powerValue with getKeyUp(f)

And here is PowerValue setup as a parameter that prevents code from setting the max and min outside of a 1 to 10 range (configurable)

```
private float powerValue = 1.0f;
public float PowerValue
{
get { return powerValue; }
set {
      if(value>10f)
         powerValue=10f;
      else if (value<1f)
         powerValue=1f;
      else
          powerValue=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the updatePowerValue(i) is a method with a parameter which assigns my original power value, correct?

Comment: Yes, I used it as a method, or you can update the variable directly if you want. Just store the value of i as the power to use when ever F is let go

Comment: I will try it out in a few minutes and I will give feedback :) No matter the outcome, thanks for taking your time in helping me.

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer using a parameter instead of a method, to avoid any code from setting the powervalue too high or too low.

Comment: Just another question. How can I add force to an object so it goes towards  where its pointed at?

Comment: probably want to make a calculation using vector3.forward and quaternion, you can't just do Transform.right